# Drawing point to point Lines dynamically using canvas

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to make a simple Graphics Application in which I can create different Shapes like (rectangles, Circles, Triangles) and also a line (from one point to another) dynamically. For the first 3 I havent had any Problems at all.  For the rect I just defined a component Rectangle and created it with create component inside the onClicked Handler of the MouseArea for my drawing area. For the triangle I worked with canvas to draw the triangle and created the component also with create component and using the onClicked handler. I mostly passed mouse.x and mouse.y to create the shapes wherever I wanted. Now for the Line I would like to define the startpoint when the mousearea is clicked and the endpoint when released. As soon as it is released I want to draw the line(using canvas). How do I do this?

For reference I added a screenshot of how I created my other items:
[image: creating the objects]

[image: drawing the triangle]

Comment: You should create a MCVE (easy with QML), and provide the code as text. Also, what exactly is your problem? Are you unable to get the coordinate? Do you get the coordinates but are unable to pass them to canvas? Do you actually get everything necessary to your Canvas but fail to draw the line correctly?

Comment: show your code as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MouseArea` has a `released` signal as well. Whenever your selectedIndex says "line", store the x and y in the `onPressed` handler and only create the line in the `onReleased` handler, using the stored position

```
MouseArea {

    property var startPoint
    onPressed: { 
        if(selectedShape.currentIndex === 3) 
            startPoint = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y) 
    }

    onReleased: {
        if(selectedShape.currentIndex === 3 && startPoint !== undefined)
        {
            createLine(startPoint, Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y) //your function goes here
        }
        startPoint = undefined        
    }
}
```

PS. don't paste code as images!

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.